# Laravel: How do I retrieve all logged in sessions for a current user

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

I am using Redis as session driver. The login works fine and session is stored in Redis. But I want to get all sessions for a particular user. I do not know how to go about it. I have searched through SO but nothing of help.

I created a different connection for sessions and can get all session keys by doing the following:

`Redis::connection('session')->keys('*')`

This will get all the keys for all users on the connection. How can I get sessions for one user only.

I do not mean `$request->session()->all()` as this will only retrieve data for the current user session.

I am trying to get a user's login sessions for all devices and allow the user to logout any device of choice.

Please don't tell me about the database driver. I can do this using database driver but not on Redis and I am using Redis

Please help

Comment: the key might only be a prefix and a session id, which would have no indication of the user

Comment: Adding a session model sounds interesting: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-current-sessions-for-user-laravel

Comment: @ChrisHaas, the link supplied is for database driver. My question was for redis. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: it is just caching the session under the session id, that is the only information you have, you would have to go through every single cached entry to see if there was some type of user id in each entry ... the concept of their being a user is only a field of the session data

Comment: Oops. I guess I will have to run to the database driver.